# datediff between sets of dates

Tags: t-sql

For some reason I am struggling with the logic of what I am trying to achieve here and was wondering if any help would be forthcoming.

[image]

Please find code for the data below -

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[temp_TEST]    Script Date: 09/07/2021 12:01:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_TEST](
    [TransactionId] [int] NULL,
    [DateFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateTo] [datetime] NULL,
    [totalvalue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [DailyAmount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [EffectiveFromDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EffectiveToDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[temp_TEST] ([TransactionId], [DateFrom], [DateTo], [totalvalue], [DailyAmount], [EffectiveFromDate], [EffectiveToDate]) VALUES (809228, CAST(N'2021-06-14T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-06-27T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(159.16 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(11.37 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'1946-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-06-22T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[temp_TEST] ([TransactionId], [DateFrom], [DateTo], [totalvalue], [DailyAmount], [EffectiveFromDate], [EffectiveToDate]) VALUES (809228, CAST(N'2021-06-14T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-06-27T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(159.16 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(11.37 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(N'2021-06-23T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-07-09T11:59:40.833' AS DateTime))
```

What I am trying to do is work out the number of days that have past between a set of dates.

So what this shows is a DateFrom and DateTo field. These are the keys dates that I want to calculate between the EffectiveFromDate and EffectiveToDate.

So what I would expect is the number of days that past between the DateFrom and DateTo....during the EffectiveFromDate and EffectiveToDate, so how many days per row have past but ONLY during the DateFrom and DateTo date.

First row - has been effective since 01/01/1946, but it ended on the 22/06/21  -that is 9 days between the DateFrom and DateTo dates. That is the 14/06 to the 22/06.

Second row  - has been effective since 23/06. It's still effective hence the effectivetodate being today's date...but it's been that value since the 23/06, so that will be 5 days between the DateFrom and DateTo. Including the 23/06.

Hope I've explained myself properly.

Comment: How your expected result should look like? Also please post the sample data as text not as image.

Comment: How could Row 2 be 6 days? Given your rule: "ONLY during the DateFrom and DateTo date" that is within the Effective Dates the difference should be 4.  6/23 to 6/27. I would assume you used the latest FromDate and the Earliest ToDate.

Comment: I will post the data here soon. Sorry I will edit the request here shortly. Basically it would be FIVE days for row 2 and NINE days for row 1. I need to know based on the EffectiveFrom and to dates - but ONLY between the DateFrom and DateTo dates. So row2 - becomes effective on the 23/06 - so including that date to the 27/06 is 5 days. row1  - was effective till 22/06. . that is NINE (9) days from the 14/06 (including that to the 22/06 when row1 was effectiveto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below, it should help.
You need to use `ISNULL` and `DATEDIFF` functions

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2021/08/25', ISNULL('2021/08/28', getdate())) AS DateDiff;

SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2021/08/25', ISNULL(null, GETDATE())) AS DateDiff;

SELECT DATEDIFF(day, EffectiveFromDate, ISNULL(EffectiveToDate, GETDATE())) AS DateDiff
FROM YourTable
```

Based on new information in question, please play around with below `case when` query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, 
case when EffectiveFromDate > DateFrom then EffectiveFromDate else DateFrom end, 
case when EffectiveToDate < DateTo then EffectiveToDate else DateTo end) AS DateDiff
FROM temp_TEST
```

it actually gives you 8 and 4 days, not 9 and 5 but this is how this function works, you can add +1 to include second date in counting, see below

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, 
case when EffectiveFromDate > DateFrom then EffectiveFromDate else DateFrom end, 
case when EffectiveToDate < DateTo then EffectiveToDate + 1 else DateTo + 1 end) AS DateDiff
FROM temp_TEST
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go - sorry what is the relevance of the hard coded dates in August?

Comment: First 2 selects are only samples, use third select in your scenario

Comment: I've added the data to the original request. . hopefully made myself a bit clearer

Comment: I was trying to go with a Case statement but wasn't quite getting there - thanks @Pawel